# Best Way to Append Integers to End of Username?

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java class that gets parameters from an "Account Request" form (like 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'email', etc.).

The Java class first gets the parameters from the form.  It then initializes a user name with the first and last name strings like so:

```
    String userName = firstName.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + lastName.toLowerCase();
```

For example, the username for "Jake Smith" would be jsmith.

Afterwards, it checks to see if this 'userName' exists in the database.  Obviously, "Jake Smith" and "John Smith" would create identical user names, "jsmith".  To account for this, I'd just like to append numbers, starting with 1, to any matching user names.

How can I append a unique number at the end of each and every conflicting username (starting with 1 and incremented by 1 for each additional conflict)?

Obviously, a more elegant solution would be to allow the user to specify their user name, but this is how the mock client wants the project to be completed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "dumb" solution, but if it's just for tests...

```
private String getUsername(){

    String userName = firstName.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + lastName.toLowerCase();
    int i=1;
    while(usernameExists(userName)){
        userName = userName.replaceAll("\\d+$","") + i++;
    }
    return userName;
}
```

Considering that `userName` don't have digits in the end.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Why do you consider it a dumb solution?  I like this approach because it replaces the whole String, rather than appending a number each time (i.e. user4 instead of user1234).

Comment: LOL! Because it doesn't works correctly if `lastName` ends with digits (for some crazy reason) and operations that may involve a lot of string changes should use another class like `StringBuilder` for better performance.

Comment: I see.  Well, this shouldn't be a problem in this instance!  There won't be any numbers, and performance won't be a major issue, as there shouldn't be too many conflicts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), something like:

```
String.format("%s%d", username, i++);
```

Answer (score 1):

If conflicts are unlikely then you could just loop until unique, staring at 1 and adding 1 each time
For example:

```
i=0;
String usernameToTry=username;
while (notUnique(usernameToTry)) {
    i++;
    usernameToTry=username+i;
}
```

If conflicts are likely then you may find this approach unsatisfactory because of the performance penalty of hitting the database (to check if unique) for every iteration of the loop. For example, if you have jsmith100 already then you don't want to check 100 times before coming up with jsmith101.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to construct the new string and [`StringBuilder#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29) to obtain it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method that uses a Map to keep track of ids.

```
class UniqueUsername {
    private static Map<String, Integer> ids = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static String getUniqueUsername(String username) {
        if (!ids.containsKey(username)) {
            ids.put(username, new Integer(0));
            return username;
        }
        ids.put(username, ids.get(username)+1);
        return username + ids.get(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: For this to be useful UniqueUsrname.ids would need to be initialised from the database on startup- assuming data persists beyond the first execution of the program